# Dataflow template not using the runtime parameters

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using a dataflow template to run cloud dataflow

I am providing some default values and calling template. Dataflow shows the pipeline options correctly in the dataflow pipeline summary. but it's not taking the runtime values.

```
class Mypipeoptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--preprocess_indir',
            help='GCS path of the data to be preprocessed',
            required=False,
            default='gs://default/dataset/'
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--output_dir_train',
            help='GCS path of the preprocessed train data',
            required=False,
            default='gs://default/train/'
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--output_dir_test',
            help='GCS path of the preprocessed test data',
            required=False,
            default='gs://default/test/'
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--output_dir_validate',
            help='GCS path of the preprocessed validate data',
            required=False,
            default='gs://default/validate/'
        )
```

Then I am checking the values are accessible

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=args)

    if args.preprocess_indir.is_accessible():
        input_dir = args.preprocess_indir
    else:
        input_dir = getValObj(args.preprocess_indir)


    if args.output_dir_train.is_accessible():
        output_train = args.output_dir_train
    else:
        output_train = getValObj(args.output_dir_train)

    if args.output_dir_test.is_accessible():
        output_test = args.output_dir_test
    else:
        output_test = getValObj(args.output_dir_test)

    if args.output_dir_validate.is_accessible():
        output_validate = args.output_dir_validate
    else:
        output_validate = getValObj(args.output_dir_validate)
```

Now when calling the template, I could see the values I wanted being passed as (Mypipeoptions)pipeine option parmater but its not used in the actual run, Instead using default options given

Comment: Which transform(s) are you passing the options to which are not using the runtime value?

Comment: None, As shown those options are used for text.io read and tfrecord.io to sink.

Comment: Can you update part of your question to include how your defining the transforms in your pipeline?

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the solution, I was assigning runtime parameters to variables and then passing it to the input or output.

When I directly passed the runtime parameters to source or sink it worked. Like the one below

```
 'Write train dataset to destination' >> beam.io.tfrecordio.WriteToTFRecord(
        file_path_prefix=args.output_dir_train
    )
```

I believe that the part I missed was that when the template is created it builds the graph and only the runtime parameters can be plugged into its runtime. Other computations are already done when building a graph.

Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Your correct. You need to pass in the value provider objects into the transforms that are consuming them so that at runtime when they are read, they can get them from PipeineOptions.

Comment: hello @user3483651, sorry to disturb you all,  I am facing similar issue ( for RuntimeValueProvider also) but unable to bypass. when u get time, can u please check. here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59894035/attribute-error-while-creating-custom-template-using-python-in-google-cloud-data?noredirect=1#comment105984153_59894035