# Attribute error while creating custom template using python in Google Cloud DataFlow

Tags: python, templates, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am facing issue while creating custom template for Cloud Dataflow.
its simple code that takes data from input bucket and loads in BigQuery.
We want to load many tables so trying to create custom template.
once this works, next step would be passing dataset also as parameter.

**Error message :**

> AttributeError: 'StaticValueProvider' object has no attribute 'datasetId'

**Code**

```
class ContactUploadOptions(PipelineOptions):
    """
    Runtime Parameters given during template execution
    path and organization parameters are necessary for execution of pipeline
    campaign is optional for committing to bigquery
    """

    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--input',
            type=str,
            help='Path of the file to read from'
            )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--output',
            type=str,
            help='Output BQ table for the pipeline')


def run(argv=None):
    """The main function which creates the pipeline and runs it."""

    global PROJECT
    from google.cloud import bigquery


    # Retrieve project Id and append to PROJECT form GoogleCloudOptions

    # Initialize runtime parameters as object
    contact_options = PipelineOptions().view_as(ContactUploadOptions)
    PROJECT = PipelineOptions().view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).project
    client = bigquery.Client(project=PROJECT)
    dataset = client.dataset('pharma')    
    data_ingestion = DataIngestion()
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
    # Save main session state so pickled functions and classes
    # defined in __main__ can be unpickled
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    # Parse arguments from command line.
    #data_ingestion = DataIngestion()

    # Instantiate pipeline
    options = PipelineOptions()
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
    (p
     | 'Read from a File' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(contact_options.input, skip_header_lines=0)
     | 'String To BigQuery Row' >> beam.Map(lambda s: data_ingestion.parse_method(s))
     | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.Write(
                beam.io.BigQuerySink(
                    contact_options.output,
                    schema='assetid:INTEGER,assetname:STRING,prodcd:INTEGER',
                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE))
     )
```

My command is as below :

```
python3 -m pharm_template --runner DataflowRunner  --project jupiter-120  --staging_location gs://input-cdc/temp/staging  --temp_location gs://input-cdc/temp/   --template_location gs://code-cdc/temp/templates/jupiter_pipeline_template
```

**What I tried :**

I tried passing `--input` and `--output`
I also tried `--experiment=use_beam_bq_sink` but to no avail.
I also tried passing datasetID

```
datasetId = StaticValueProvider(str, 'pharma')
```

but no luck.
If any one has created template that loads in BQ , then I can take cue and fix this issue.

Comment: Hello, I am investigating your issue. Have you used this template[1] to instantiate your pipeline using _ValueProvider_?Link:[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#using-valueprovider-in-your-functions

Comment: Hi, I was just wondering if you seolved you issue already. Also, if you could tell me that the error persists using directrunner.

Comment: yes, I was able to bypass the issue by passing this way in the  beam.io.BigQuerySink(("%s:%s.%s" % (PROJECT, DATASET, TABLE)),... working on making it generic as it still needs default value for runtime value provider.

Comment: That's great! At the moment you do not have any other issues, right?

Comment: the current issue I have is - while creating templates, it still needs the runtime provider value, which then becomes part of the template file. if that's the case, then template won't act as template in true sense. how can I bypass that.

Comment: hello @AlexandreMoraes, do you know how to prepare generic templates. the templates I prepare pulls the runtime values while creating the template and hardcodes it.  I can't use any other value. facing issue using the RuntimeValueProvider

Comment: Hello @akash sharma, I am on it and I will be right back at you.

Comment: @akashsharma Sorry, I haven't seen your comment. Did you fix the issue? if not, I will look it to it.